# Подсчет количества вхождений букв в строку с помощью потока (Stream)

Tags: java, java-stream, java-8

Есть определенная строка(например `"Some example"`). Нужно определить количество вхождений каждой буквы в строке с помощью потока Stream и при этом без использования циклов, if и прочего(лишь рекурсия, потоки Stream и его методы вроде `map`, `reduce`, `filter`).

Я сделал из строки массив символов, который потом превратил в список c помощью рекурсивного метода `toCharList`.

```
String text = "Some example".toLowerCase.replaceAll("\\s", "")
List<Character> textInChar = toCharList(text.toCharArray(), 0);

static public List<Character> toCharList(char[] textChars, int i) {

    if(textChars.length == i) return new ArrayList<>();

    List<Character> ret =  new ArrayList<>();
    ret.add(textChars[i]);
    ret.addAll(toCharList(textChars, i + 1));


    return ret;
}
```

Затем из этого списка создал хэш-мапу c помощью перегруженного метода `toCharMap`. Таким образом получил я список всех не повторяющихся букв, которые есть в строке.

```
Map<Character, Integer>  countChar = toCharMap(textInChar);

public static Map<Character, Integer> toCharMap(List<Character> l) {
    return toCharMap(l.iterator());
}


public static Map<Character, Integer> toCharMap(Iterator it) {
    if (!it.hasNext()) return new HashMap<>();

    Map<Character, Integer> ret = new HashMap<>();
    ret.put((Character)it.next(), 0);
    ret.putAll(toCharMap(it));

    return ret;
}
```

Но как теперь их посчитать в потоке, например с помощью `filter` и `reduce`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Из строки массив символов лучше получать так:

```
String text = ("Some example").toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", "");
List<Character> textInChar = Chars.asList(text.toCharArray());
```

или:

```
textInChar = text.chars().mapToObj(e->(char)e).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

2) Xэш-мапу не повторяющихся символов лучше получить тогда уж так:

```
Map<Character, Integer> countChar = textInChar.stream().collect(HashMap::new, (m, c) -> {
            m.put(c, 1);
            m.put(c, 1);
        }, HashMap::putAll);
```

А всю задачу я бы решил так:

```
textInChar = text.chars().mapToObj(e->(char)e).collect(Collectors.toList());
Map<Character, Integer> countChar = textInChar.stream().collect(HashMap::new, (m, c) -> {
            if(m.containsKey(c))
                m.put(c, m.get(c) + 1);
            else
                m.put(c, 1);
        }, HashMap::putAll);
```

Проверим:

```
countChar.forEach( (k, v) -> LOG.debug(k + " -> " + v));
```

Выведет:

```
p -> 1
a -> 1
s -> 1
e -> 3
x -> 1
l -> 1
m -> 2
o -> 1
```

**UPD:**

```
if(m.containsKey(c))
    m.put(c, m.get(c) + 1);
else
    m.put(c, 1);
```

Можно сократить до:

```
m.put(c, m.containsKey(c) ? (m.get(c) + 1) : 1);
```

Comment: А ещё можно убрать `containsKey` заменив его проверкой на `null` результата `get`. Вдруг быстрее будет? =) `m.put(c, (m.get(c)!=null) ? (m.get(c) + 1) : 1);`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не всегда верно. Ибо `A return value of null does not necessarily indicate that the map contains no mapping for the key; it's also possible that the map explicitly maps the key to null`. В данном контексте можно, но в общем случае нет)

Comment: На C# было бы так: `text.GroupBy(c => c).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count())` http://ideone.com/mR0ecp

Comment: Можно для подсчета символов использовать `map.merge( c, 1, Integer::sum );`

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш вариант решения. А что означает двоеточие после мапы HashMap::putAl?
Подобное двоеточие видел лишь в циклах forEach.

Comment: @EvheniiVasylenko это просто новый синтаксис, который сокращает код. Это логически эквивалентно этому коду: `(map, item) -> map.putAll(item)`

Comment: весь collect сокращается до .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), v -> 1, (v1, v2) -> v1 + v2)). Третий параметр - merger, при совпадении значений

Answer (score 4):

Для группировки элементов Stream можно воспользоваться коллектором [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-). Кроме варианта с одним агрументом (функцией-классификатором) у него есть вариант, принимающий еще один коллектор, c помощью которого будет выполнена редукция групп к одному значению:

```
// Character::valueOf принимает char, а поток у нас из int
String output = "Some example".chars().mapToObj( ch -> new Character( (char)ch ) )
        // сгруппировать по символам, внутри группы подсчитать количество
        .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( Function.identity(), Collectors.counting() ) )
        // группировка возвращает Map<Character, Integer> с количеством разных символов
        .entrySet().stream()
        // если надо выбрать только встречающиеся 1 раз
        //.filter( entry -> entry.getValue() == 1 )
        // раз forEach плохо :)
        //.forEach( entry -> System.out.printf( "'%s' -> %d%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() ) );
        .map( entry -> String.format( "'%s' -> %d%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() ) )
        .collect( Collectors.joining() );

System.out.println( output );
```

Comment: В условии сказано, что надо без цикла, а у вас `forEach`.

Comment: @Suvitruf это просто вывод, но я обновил ответ :)

Comment: Да, не заметил)

Comment: группировка возвращает Map<Character, Long>

Answer (score 0):

```java
String string = "Some example";

Map<Character, AtomicInteger> result = IntStream
    .range(0, string.length())
    // .parallel() // can be parallel for very big strings
    .mapToObj(string::charAt)
    .collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
            Function.identity(),
            c -> new AtomicInteger(1),
            (count1, count2) -> {
                count1.addAndGet(count2.getAndSet(0));
                return count1;
            }
        )
    );
```

для сравнения императивная реализация:

```java
String string = "Some example";

Map<Character, AtomicInteger> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    map
        .computeIfAbsent(string.charAt(i), character -> new AtomicInteger())
        .incrementAndGet();
}
```

которая гораздо производительнее при любых раскладах